# Create transparent gif/png with dynamic dimensions

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

Trying to create a gif or png with user-defined dimensions. The closest I've got is with this:

```
$imgWidth = intval($_GET['x']);
$imgWidth = $imgWidth > 0 ? $imgWidth : 1;

$imgHeight = intval($_GET['y']);
$imgHeight = $imgHeight > 0 ? $imgHeight : 1;

$im = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth, $imgHeight);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

imagecolortransparent($im, $white);

header('Content-Type: image/png');    
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

This *appears* to work but on closer inspection it actually creates an image with the correct dimensions but with a 0 x 0px foreground. This is causing the image to display incorrectly in some clients, e.g. I get a memory error in Photoshop. I can open it in Fireworks but it displays the zero pixel bitmap at the extreme top left in front of a transparent background:
[image]

I tried adding `imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, $white);` directly after `imagecolortransparent($im, $white);` but it has no effect.

What am I missing?

Comment: '...creates an image with the correct dimensions but with a 0 x 0px foreground.'  What do you mean by 'foreground'?  PNG is a raster format; a 100x100px image is a 100x100px image.  I ran your code with `?x=100&y=200` and got a transparent 100x200px rectangle, as expected.  Can you provide more detail in your question?

Comment: @timclutton Edited to explain what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a peculiarity of the Adobe applications you mention. I don't have a copy of those so I can't test with them, but every other application I've tried renders the image as expected.

Perhaps try the following to see if the resulting image is more acceptable to Adobe:

```
$imgWidth = intval($_GET['x']);
$imgWidth = $imgWidth > 0 ? $imgWidth : 1;

$imgHeight = intval($_GET['y']);
$imgHeight = $imgHeight > 0 ? $imgHeight : 1;

$im = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth, $imgHeight);
imagealphablending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
$white = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127); // fully transparent white.

imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

At a guess, I would say the problem occurs because you're setting the transparency as a property of the *image* rather than as a property of the *colour* (or, more accurately, pixel).

The former is ordinarily used for palette-based images (`imagecreate`) where the pixel is either fully opaque or fully transparent and cannot otherwise appear in the image. That is, if red (`ff0000`) is considered fully transparent by the image, *all* red pixels will be transparent and the colour won't display at all.

For a true-colour image (`imagecreatetruecolor`) the ability to specify the transparency as a property of the pixel is a better approach since it enables partial transparency.  This means you can use the same colour with a different transparency level for different pixels.

The script above uses the latter approach.